# A word to mean shine

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

When sunlight fall on new leaves, they glow. Is there any word to describe this shiny glow of the surface of the leaf?

Comment: What's wrong with *shine*? Maybe you could show us a photo of what you mean?

Comment: In addition to that picture suggested by @curiousdannii you could also look up _shine_ in a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/shine), and tell us why words like _sheen, luster,_ and _shimmer_ aren't very suitable to your needs.

Comment: I feel certain Wordsworth will have used some elegant way of describing it. You could start by ploughing through his works!

Comment: The leaves appear to be *illuminated*; they are *lighted up*; they seem to be  [*fluorescent*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fluorescent); the leaves *sparkle* and *shine*; ...

Comment: You want a term for the general diffuse reflection, or a *specular* reflection off the surface of the leaf? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that the leaves appear to glow in the sunshine when seen from below, I'd say they are *glowing translucently*.

I don't think there's a single-word term for this phenomenon besides the basic word *glow*.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was about to put a picture but you gave me exactly what I was looking for! I was trying to find a word that would mean "glow from below".

Comment: I wouldn't like glow as it is usually reseved for sources of light rather than reflected light. Maybe "gleam"

Comment: @Martin - The OP's comment to my answer confirms that she is not talking about light being **reflected off** the surface of the leaves, but **transmitted through** the leaves.

Comment: Reflected or transmitted, the source of the light is not the leaves themselves, and I would consider "glow" in this context as erroneous.

Comment: @Martin - By your logic, a gel spotlight that lights up a stage is not glowing either, because the gel through with the light passes from the bulb is not technically the source of the light either. Your objection is frivolous.

Comment: I have stated my opinion. If you wish to consider it frivolous, that is your opinion,

Answer (score 1):

Candescent - "begin to gleam"
eg: Candescent Moon

Comment: I would have chosen "the candescent leaves" too.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something more fulsome than 'shiny'. How about [refulgent](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/refulgent)?

Answer (score 0):

> The leaves appear ***fluorescent***
>
> [fluorescent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fluorescent): 2. Glowing as if with fluorescence; vivid: bright fluorescent colors.